# Rails with multiple databases, but every user should decide which db to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

i'm searching for a way to to let the user decide which connection he wants to use. But his decision should not affect other users.

Next thing is: all users should uses the same MVCs, cause on all databases are eqaul table stucture, just other data.

I use oracle db with oracle_enhanced adapter.

I tried with connection_establish method, but it influences all users.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please explain why you need this feature? What do you try to achieve? Did you consider scoping the records in the database instead of using different databases?

Comment: This Feature is needed because, the main functionality are some pl/SQL functions and a specific table stucture. The Rails App is only to control this pl/sql program. And i want to install the program on more than one Oracle instance, so the user can decide on which he would work within the Rails App